# Photoshop selection feather and cut/paste behavior (pixel loss)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When cutting(deleting) a selection with a feather it completely deletes all that is inside the selection and creates the feather with gradually increasing opacity outside the selection line.
On the other hand when the cut selection is pasted (e.g. to a different layer) it has the feather effect applied inside the selection. Thus if I cut a selection from one layer and paste it to a layer above it I have a part of the image along the selection edge lost.

Is there a way around this (still using the feather effect), so that when you cut from a layer and paste to a layer above you don't have anything lost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just before pasting, you need to deselect (Ctrl-D on Windows or Menu: Select\Deselect).

When pasting, if you have a selection, the paste will be restricted to the selection. The feather result is already included in the copied image.

Comment: You're right. What I was confused about is that when you cut you get this partially transparent border (feather?) with both the 'hole' left and the bit in the clipboard and when you paste to a layer above and align the piece with where it was in the layer below you don't get the original image because of the way the two overlapping transparent regions get combined. So it is still partly transparent and I was expecting to get the original completely opaque image.